# Accessing object's properties in an array

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i<=rowData.length;i++){
        alert(rowData[i].title);
    }
```

i have a some five objects in an array. those objects have title, but when i try to access them, it says `cannot read property title from sundefined`.

How can i differentiate these objects, when i don't have the index or the name of object.

Let's take `rowData = [object,object,object];`

Now i want to access a specified object, but how can i know that this object is what i am looking for.

Comment: How is the object defined?  Can you post the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want less than not less than or equal to.